# NetSuite. How to select all attached files for current user (filter by InternalId)

Tags: c#, netsuite

I am using C# implementation of netsuite api from web reference com.netsuite.webservices

I released filter fileSearch.basic by name (you can see it commented) it is working fine.

Please help to write function to achieve all attached files for current user. Something is wrong in this code, it filters nothing and showing me all files as it is without any filter. Please help me.

```
public static void GetFileAttachmentByCustomerId(string customerId)
    {
        using (NetSuiteService netSuiteService = GetNetSuiteService())
        {
            FileSearch fileSearch = new FileSearch();

            // this works fine (filter files by name)
            //SearchStringField nameSearchParams = new SearchStringField
            //{
            //    @operator = SearchStringFieldOperator.contains,
            //    operatorSpecified = true,
            //    searchValue = "some name",
            //};
            //fileSearch.basic = new FileSearchBasic() { name = nameSearchParams };


            // this code not filter files at all
            {
                RecordRef nsCustomerRef = new RecordRef
                {
                    internalId = customerId,
                    type = RecordType.customer,
                    typeSpecified = true,
                };
                SearchMultiSelectField shopperSearchParam = new SearchMultiSelectField
                {
                    @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
                    operatorSpecified = true,
                    searchValue = new RecordRef[] { nsCustomerRef }
                };

                fileSearch.shopperJoin = new CustomerSearchBasic { internalId = shopperSearchParam };
            }

            SearchResult result = netSuiteService.search(fileSearch);

            // Get connected objects
            {
                Customer customer = GetCustomerById(netSuiteService, customerId);
                Account account = GetAccountById(netSuiteService, "301395"); //
                Folder folder = GetFolderById(netSuiteService, "3962");
            }

            File file = (File)result.recordList.First();
            byte[] fileContent = GetFileContentByInternalId(file.internalId);
        }
    }
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var nsCustomerRef = new RecordRef
        {
            internalId = "4",
            type = RecordType.employee,
            typeSpecified = true,
        };

        var currentUser = new SearchMultiSelectField()
        {
            operatorSpecified = true,
            @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
            searchValue = new List<RecordRef>() {nsCustomerRef}.ToArray()
        };

        var fileSearchBasic = new FileSearchBasic() {owner = currentUser};
        var fileSearch = new FileSearch() { basic = fileSearchBasic };

        var result = netSuiteService.search(fileSearch);
        var file = (File)result.recordList.First();
```